# "Question belongs on another site" close reason removed?

Tags: support, migration

I was trying to flag https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/211306/36229 to be moved to Stackoverflow, but the option seems to have disappeared. Was it removed? Did I just miss it?

I'm using the mobile site, if that's relevant.

Comment: I couldn't see either (from web site). Minor off-topic note: I think that question should not be migrated to SO (lack of research, no reproducible example; probably it would be smashed there).

Comment: Same for me, looks like our off-topic close reasons have changed. This is news to me!

Answer (score 10):

You can't migrate the question because it's already been migrated from GIS:

[image]

If it's off topic here just vote to close/delete and that will reject the migration. Then ask the GIS mods to re-migrate the question to Stack Overflow (though it's not a brilliant question so might not last long on SO either).

Comment: at least it's on-topic there!